# XML parsing, TXMLDocument

Tags: xml, delphi, xml-parsing, txmldocument

I have a problem with parsing XML.

How to get field values `se_url` and `phrase`?
I need to get `link1_1`, `link1_2`, `key1`, `link2_1`, `link2_2`, `key2`... 
which are in `se_url` and `phrase`.

I did not find in Google how to do it (also did not find a manual on how to work with `TXMLDocument`).

```
<doc>
  <date2>20120214</date2>
  <date1>20120214</date1>
  <data count="116">
    <row>
      <search_engines count="2">
        <search_engine>
          <se_url>link1_1</se_url>
          <se_page>1</se_page>
          <se_id>2</se_id>
        </search_engine>
        <search_engine>
          <se_url>link1_2</se_url>
          <se_page>1</se_page>
          <se_id>3</se_id>
        </search_engine>
      </search_engines>
      <denial>0.4889</denial>
      <visits>45</visits>
      <page_views>52</page_views>
      <phrase>key1</phrase>
      <visit_time>126</visit_time>
      <depth>1.1556</depth>
    </row>
    <row>
      <search_engines count="2">
        <search_engine>
          <se_url>link2_1</se_url>
          <se_page>1</se_page>
          <se_id>3</se_id>
        </search_engine>
        <search_engine>
          <se_url>link2_2</se_url>
          <se_page>1</se_page>
          <se_id>6</se_id>
        </search_engine>
      </search_engines>
      <denial>0.5714</denial>
      <visits>42</visits>
      <page_views>50</page_views>
      <phrase>key2</phrase>
      <visit_time>109</visit_time>
      <depth>1.1905</depth>
    </row>
  </data>
</doc>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I understand that English is probably not your first language since the document is hosted on a `.ru` domain, but this question doesn't make any sense.  Would you mind editing it and providing a bit more detail as to specifically what you're looking for?

Comment: Posting most of your question in an off-site link means it becomes meaningless if that other site becomes unavailable or goes away. Please edit your question to provide at least part of the XML document here, so that your question remains useful to others in the future and is searchable. While you're editing that part, you can provide more information about what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far, and explain how it hasn't worked as expected. Thanks. :0

Comment: dredei I tried to show you what Ken means, hope my edit helps? You should still expand your question to say what you've tried. Did you even try MSXML DOM or OmniXML or you just tried to parse without an XML parser?

Comment: @Warren, you've just removed all incentive for the poster to come back and edit the question. (You've done the same thing as doing someone's entire homework assignment, and then telling them they should read the book afterward.)

Comment: updated first post and changed the link :)

Comment: @dredei: Don't change the link. Post a snippet of the XML here, as we have asked multiple times. Once again, links **off-site** are not suitable - your question should be able to stand on it's own here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
uses ComObj, MSXML;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  xml: IXMLDOMDocument;
  node: IXMLDomNode;
  nodes_row, nodes_se: IXMLDomNodeList;
  i, j: Integer;
  url: string;
begin
  // put url or file name
  url := 'http://softez.pp.ua/gg.xml';

  xml := CreateOleObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM') as IXMLDOMDocument;
  xml.async := False;
  xml.load(url); // or use loadXML to load XML document using a supplied string
  if xml.parseError.errorCode <> 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('XML Load error:' + xml.parseError.reason);

  Memo1.Clear;
  nodes_row := xml.selectNodes('/doc/data/row');
  for i := 0 to nodes_row.length - 1 do
  begin
    node := nodes_row.item[i];
    Memo1.Lines.Add('phrase=' + node.selectSingleNode('phrase').text);
    nodes_se := node.selectNodes('search_engines/search_engine/se_url');
    for j := 0 to nodes_se.length - 1 do
    begin
      node := nodes_se.item[j];
      Memo1.Lines.Add('url=' + node.text);
    end;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('--------------');
  end;
end;
```

**Result:**

```
phrase=key1
url=link1_1
url=link1_2
--------------
phrase=key2
url=link2_1
url=link2_2
--------------
```

A Reference to [IXMLDOMDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @KenWhite, Thank *you* for caring about the quality of the questions on SO :) ( BTW, Do you know why my code is not colorized? :/ )

Comment: I don't know why it's not being syntax-highlighted. I went and looked at the source, and it looks fine. I even added an explicit language comment with no change. ???

Comment: One more question: how to get the attribute value?

Comment: `node.attributes.getNamedItem('count').text`.

Answer (score 4):

If you first include these 3 general purpose library routines ....

```
uses XMLDoc, XMLIntf, xmldom;

function CreateXMLDocument( var Owner1: TComponent): TXMLDocument;
begin
Owner1 := TComponent.Create( nil);
result  := TXMLDocument.Create( Owner1);
result.Options := [doNodeAutoCreate, doNodeAutoIndent, doAttrNull,
                   doAutoPrefix, doNamespaceDecl];
result.DOMVendor := GetDOMVendor( 'MSXML');
end;

function XPATHSelect( const FocusNode: IXMLNode; const sXPath: string): TArray<IXMLNode>;
var
  DomNodeSelect: IDomNodeSelect;
  DOMNode      : IDomNode;
  DocAccess    : IXmlDocumentAccess;
  Doc          : TXmlDocument;
  DOMNodes     : IDOMNodeList;
  iDOMNode     : integer;
begin
SetLength( result, 0);
if assigned( FocusNode) and
   Supports( FocusNode.DOMNode, IDomNodeSelect, DomNodeSelect) then
    DOMNodes := DomNodeSelect.SelectNodes( sXPath);
if not assigned( DOMNodes) then exit;
SetLength( result, DOMNodes.Length);
for iDOMNode := 0 to DOMNodes.Length - 1 do
  begin
  Doc := nil;
  DOMNode := DOMNodes.item[iDOMNode];
  if Supports( DOMNode, IXmlDocumentAccess, DocAccess) then
    Doc := DocAccess.DocumentObject;
  result[ iDOMNode] := TXmlNode.Create( DOMNode, nil, Doc) as IXMLNode;
  end
end;


function XPATHSelectFirst( const FocusNode: IXMLNode; const sXPath: string; var SelectedNode: IXMLNode): boolean;
var
  DomNodeSelect: IDomNodeSelect;
  DOMNode      : IDomNode;
  DocAccess    : IXmlDocumentAccess;
  Doc          : TXmlDocument;
begin
SelectedNode := nil;
if assigned( FocusNode) and
   Supports( FocusNode.DOMNode, IDomNodeSelect, DomNodeSelect) then
  DOMNode := DomNodeSelect.selectNode( sXPath);
if assigned( DOMNode) and
   Supports( DOMNode.OwnerDocument, IXmlDocumentAccess, DocAccess) then
  Doc := DocAccess.DocumentObject;
if Assigned( DOMNode) then
  SelectedNode := TXmlNode.Create( DOMNode, nil, Doc);
result := assigned( SelectedNode)
end;
```

**Then A much neater solution is ...**

```
procedure TForm2.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  DocumentSource =  'http://softez.pp.ua/gg.xml';
var
  Doc: IXMLDocument;
  DocOwner: TComponent;
  RowNode, PhraseNode, UrlNode: IXMLNode;

  procedure PutLn( const LineFmt: string; const Args: array of const);
  begin
  memo2.Lines.Add( Format( LineFmt, Args))
  end;

begin
memo2.Clear;
Doc := CreateXMLDocument( DocOwner);
Doc.LoadFromFile( DocumentSource);
for RowNode in XPATHSelect( Doc.DocumentElement, '//row[phrase]') do
  begin
  if not XPATHSelectFirst( RowNode, 'phrase', PhraseNode) then continue;
  PutLn( 'phrase=%s', [PhraseNode.NodeValue]);
  for UrlNode in XPATHSelect( RowNode, 'search_engines/search_engine/se_url') do
    PutLn( 'url=%s', [UrlNode.NodeValue]);
  PutLn('--------------',[])
  end;
DocOwner.Free;
end;
```

This was tested on Delphi 2010 and works a treat.

Answer (score 4):

And just for good measure, here is another answer, provided you are not afraid to mix in a little XSLT !

```
const Transform =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
'<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> ' +
' <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>' +
' <xsl:template match="text()|@*"/>' +
' <xsl:template match="//row">' +
'  <xsl:text>phrase=</xsl:text>' +
'  <xsl:value-of select="phrase"/>' +
'  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>' +
'  <xsl:apply-templates/>' +
'  <xsl:text>--------------&#10;</xsl:text>' +
' </xsl:template>' +
' <xsl:template match="search_engines/search_engine/se_url">' +
'  <xsl:text>url=</xsl:text>' +
'  <xsl:value-of select="."/>' +
'  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>' +
' </xsl:template>' +
'</xsl:stylesheet>';


procedure TForm2.btn1Click( Sender: TObject);
const
  DocumentSource =  'http://softez.pp.ua/gg.xml';
var
  Doc, Style: IXMLDocument;
  DocOwner, StyleOwner: TComponent;
  sOut: widestring;
begin
  memo2.Clear;
  Doc := CreateXMLDocument( DocOwner);
  Doc.LoadFromFile( DocumentSource);
  Style := CreateXMLDocument( StyleOwner);
  Style.LoadFromXML( Transform);
  Doc.DocumentElement.TransformNode( Style.DocumentElement, sOut);
  memo2.Lines.Add( sOut);
  DocOwner.Free;  
  StyleOwner.Free
end;
```

Comment: I seem to be getting an error. It says "Undeclared identifier: 'CreateXMLDocument'". I am using Delphi 10.1 Berlin Starter Edition and FireMonkey. Then I also have the following in my uses list that is related to XML: Xml.xmldom, Xml.XMLIntf, Xml.adomxmldom, Xml.XMLDoc