# Delphi extract string between tags twice

Tags: xml, delphi, text, tags

I found this code as I run into the same poblem: retrieving the text between two tags. It works, but it only grabs the first occurrance of hello.

```
function ExtractTextInsideGivenTagEx(const Tag, Text: string): string;
var
  StartPos1, StartPos2, EndPos: integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  result := '';
  StartPos1 := Pos('<' + Tag, Text);
  EndPos := Pos('</' + Tag + '>', Text);
  StartPos2 := 0;
  for i := StartPos1 + length(Tag) + 1 to EndPos do
    if Text[i] = '>' then
    begin
      StartPos2 := i + 1;
      break;
    end;


  if (StartPos2 > 0) and (EndPos > StartPos2) then
    result := Copy(Text, StartPos2, EndPos - StartPos2);
end;
```

But what If you have

`<sample>hello1</sample><sample>hello2</sample><sample>hello3</sample><sample>hello4</sample>`

and you want to grab the text of the first TWO occurrances ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 or in other words, use a parser

Comment: `<!-- what happens now ?</mytag> -->`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your search function remember `StartPos` and use [Pos()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Pos) with an optional offset parameter.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

function ExtractTextInsideGivenTagEx(const Tag, Text: string;
  var StartPos: Integer): string;
var
  StartPos2, EndPos: Integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  StartPos := Pos('<' + Tag, Text, StartPos); // PosEx() in older Delphi versions
  EndPos := Pos('</' + Tag + '>', Text, StartPos);
  StartPos2 := 0;
  for i := StartPos + Length(Tag) + 1 to EndPos do
  begin
    if Text[i] = '>' then
    begin
      StartPos2 := i + 1;
      break;
    end;
  end;
  if (StartPos2 > 0) and (EndPos > StartPos2) then
  begin
    Result := Copy(Text, StartPos2, EndPos - StartPos2);
    StartPos := StartPos2;
  end;
end;

procedure Test(const Sample, aString: String);
var
  s: String;
  StartPos,foundTags: Integer;
begin
  StartPos := 1;
  foundTags := 0;
  repeat
    s := ExtractTextInsideGivenTagEx(Sample, aString, StartPos);
    if (s <> '') then
    begin
      WriteLn(s);
      Inc(StartPos, Length(Sample));
      Inc(foundTags);
    end;
  until (s = '') or (foundTags = 2);
end;

begin
  Test('sample',
    '<sample>hello1</sample><sample>hello2</sample><sample>hello3</sample><sample>hello4</sample>');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

---

Now having provided a solution for the example XML text, note that the XML (and HTML) document can be far more complex than this example. This means it is easy to loose track of tags without a complete fullblown parser. See [XML parsing, TXMLDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9282370/576719).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your example. I tried to use it for XE6, but it throws an E/A Error.

Comment: You mean an I/O error (in English). The example here works fine for me in XE6. Are you pasting the code into a GUI application? Then replace WriteLn with something that writes to a memo for demonstration.

Comment: Yes you are right, the writeln caused the I/O error. Many, many thanks, this was really helpful !

Comment: @LURD I know that you know this, but you ought to mention that this won't work for general XML or HTML, only text that fits a specific format.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes only use a simple search engine (or TRegEx) if the format is well known to fit the document which to search into.