# XML parsing in Delphi XE8

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-xe8

Hi I'm a newbe on programming.
But I have to parse XML file using Delphi.
I found one article on this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282370/xml-parsing-txmldocument) but I can not solve my question.
I have a XML file like belowed.
I have to get datas from **Ccy, CcyNm_EN, Rate, date**.
I'm not a lazy but I can not find solution, because I'm newbe, Please help me solve it.

```
<CBU_Curr name="CBU Currency XML by ISO 4217">
 <CcyNtry ID="840">
  <Ccy>USD</Ccy>
  <CcyNm_RU>Доллар США</CcyNm_RU>
  <CcyNm_UZ>AQSh dollari</CcyNm_UZ>
  <CcyNm_UZC>АҚШ доллари</CcyNm_UZC>
  <CcyNm_EN>U.S. Dollar</CcyNm_EN>
  <CcyMnrUnts>2</CcyMnrUnts>
  <Nominal>1</Nominal>
  <Rate>2909.25</Rate>
  <date>11.05.2016</date>
 </CcyNtry>
</CBU_Curr>
```

Comment: Use an XML parser. Which parser would you like to use? Have you gone through the tutorials for that parser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/263419/62576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everybody.
I found a right way and I wrote my code;

```
s1:='http://127.0.0.1/rates/USD/';
date1:=FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', dt1.Date);
XMLDocument1.LoadFromFile(s1 + date1 + '/');
XMLDocument1.Active := true;
Stock := XMLDocument1.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0];
  Edit1.text := Stock.ChildNodes['Ccy'].Text;
  Edit2.text := Stock.ChildNodes['CcyNm_UZ'].Text;
  Edit3.text := Stock.ChildNodes['Rate'].Text;
  Edit4.text := Stock.ChildNodes['date'].Text;
```

Stock.Resync;

Comment: You can edit your question if you want to add more details. Do not misuse the answers for that