# Delphi simple xml parse

Tags: xml, delphi

I need to parse out some values from xml file. The problem is - that I must do it with Delphi =(. 
the file is quite simple

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Items version="1.0">
  <Item BackupFileName="d:\data.bak">
    <Rating Rate="TOP"/>
  </Item>
  <Item BackupFileName="d:\data2.bak">
    <Rating Rate="OTHER"/>
  </Item>
  ....
</Items>
```

And I just need an array of strings with this filepaths {"d:\data.bak", "d:\data2.bak", ... } 
 I have googled a little and found a solution (as I thought) like

```
 url := 'D:\Backups.xml';
  xml := CreateOleObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM') as IXMLDOMDocument;
  xml.async := False;
  xml.load(url); // or use loadXML to load XML document using a supplied string
  if xml.parseError.errorCode <> 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('XML Load error:' + xml.parseError.reason);

  nodes_row := xml.selectNodes('/Items');
  for i := 0 to nodes_row.length - 1 do
  begin
    node := nodes_row.item[i];
    result := node.selectSingleNode('Item').text;
end;
```

But result seems to be always void. Could you please provide or refer an easy solution for this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be  `xml.selectNodes('/Items/Item');` as you use a for loop afterwards?

Comment: I have got an access violation O_o

Comment: Why not use the built in XML parser classes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML parsing, TXMLDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282370/xml-parsing-txmldocument)

Comment: https://www.thoughtco.com/parsing-and-manipulating-xml-documents-1058477

Comment: You're getting the AV because none of your nodes contain text. They have attributes, which have values, but contain no text. A node with text would be `<node>Some text</node>`, where the text is between `>` and `<`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `IXMLNode.Attributes` property Or the `IXMLNode.AttributeNodes` property, since your nodes don't contain text, you actually looking for attribute text.